# How do I set logging priority in zend framework2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to be able to control the logging priority in my zf2 application. I currently do

```
 $priority = \Zend\Log\Logger::INFO;
 $log->addWriter($writer, $priority);
```

to write to a log file, which works great. It just seems that the log level is stuck at Zend\Log\Logger::DEBUG no matter what I set $priority to.

Comment: Not 100% but I think that the second parameter to `addWriter` is the priority of the writer, eg if you have multiple writers, the priority is the order in which writer is called first. Not the actual log level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you clarify your question? Do you want to prioritize writers or limit messages priority?

If you want limit logging by message priority you must use Filter\Priority. Like this:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('/path/to/logfile');
$logger->addWriter($writer);

$filter = new \Zend\Log\Filter\Priority(Logger::CRIT);
$writer->addFilter($filter);
```